# Is it possible to have a dynamic data ASP.net web application using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, dynamic-data

Is it possible to have a dynamic data ASP.net web application using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web Application, this is how it is called in menu (VS2010 and VS2008).

File->New->Project...->Visual C#->Web